# JWT - TOKEN_EXPIRED after second refresh

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

I am developing an API server with laravel and [tymon/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth). In the test envirovment TTL - 1 min, TTL_REFRESH - 2 min. Don't understand how the following algoritm works:

1. The user logged in and received a token
2. TTL of the token is expired, but TTL_REFRESH is not. User sends a request to the server to refresh the token
3. The user uses a new token, but has not updated it in time. Token is expired again.
4. When user trying to refresh the token at second time (first time was at 2 step), server sends `TOKEN_EXPIRED`

If after 1 and 2 steps try to refresh the token with not-expired TTL, token will be refreshed. But if we refresh it once after expired, after second time (with expired token) server will send to client `TOKEN_EXPIRED`.

My question is why after the second token update with expired TTL, server not refreshes the token but send `TOKEN_EXPIRED`?

Answer (score 1):

I think refresh token has been invalidate after first use

you must use new refresh token to refresh your jwt token and get new one

Comment: I have only one token, no refresh token provided by jwt-auth. When I refresh it, I just send a request to the server with `authorization: Bearer *token*` header.

Comment: You must have refresh token to refresh jwt token, i suggest you to read this documenation, that is based on slim php framework: https://oauth2.thephpleague.com